# How to remove the 'back' button/ how to keep the back button

Tags: javascript, html, css, coldfusion

CHANGED: If the user is coming from the 'home page', the ‘Search Supplies’ page shall have one button on the bottom of the page: the ‘Back’ button.

ADDED: If the user is coming from a web page other than the home page, the ‘Search Supplies’ page shall have no buttons.

How would I remove the 'back' button but at the same time keep it?  When you access the page directly from the home page the 'back' button needs to be there, but when you come to the 'Search Supplies' page from a different tab other than home, it should not be there.

Comment: what about always having a 'Home' button instead?

Comment: You could set a cookie on the homepage that the search page can read and delete, include a back button on the page, if the cookie isn't there then no button is supplied.

Comment: @OriginalSyn, What is the advantage of using cookies?  Your solution seems like it add complexity.  The OP is using coldfusion.  That means it is possible at the server side to alter the html rendered to the client.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (document.referrer != "http://example.com/homepage.html")
  document.getElementById("back").style.display = "none";
```

Here is another example by domain:

```
var reffererURL = document.referrer.substring(document.referrer.indexOf("/")+2);
if(reffererURL.substring(0,reffererURL.indexOf("/")) == location.host)
  document.getElementById("back").style.display = "block";
else
  document.getElementById("back").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: true... not the way I'd like to see it done, but this was tagged js, so just throwing it out there.

Comment: thanks guys! .. Joseph, how would you like to see this done, just curious if there is another way, thanks.

Comment: this kind of js is a little messy and relies on a hard coded link, which just means more maintenance down the road.  Now that I think about it, it might be better to check the domain instead (a little more dynamic and reliable): var reffererURL = document.referrer.substring(document.referrer.indexOf("/")+2); if(document.referrer == reffererURL.substring(0,reffererURL.indexOf("/"))

Comment: above is a little more complex but maybe a bit better

Comment: yeah it maybe a bit better to go this route, I'll try that out, thanks again Joseph.

Comment: no problem :) if you need to know how to implement the domain compare, I can add it to my post.

Comment: oh yeah, that would be really helpful if you could show me how to implement that, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With *magic*

Try to view the HTTP_REFFERER from some server or client variable to see where the user is coming from (or not coming from) and work from there.